# Array resize on worksheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I always use Resize() function like this:

```
Cells(1, "B").Resize(counter, ColumnCount).value = MyArraY
```

But MyArray always has a different format of array inside to put items to worksheet

Sometimes to get the same range I need to use

`so if MyArraY filling this way`

```
                        For y = 1 To .ListCount
                            If .Selected(y - 1) Then
                                ' load subarray into array
                                ListB = vbNullString
                                For f = 1 To .ColumnCount
                                    ListB = ListB & "·" & .List(y - 1, f - 1)
                                Next f
                                MyArraY(counter) = Split(Mid(ListB, 2), "·")
                                counter = counter + 1
                            End If
                        Next y
I must use

Cells(1, "B").Resize(counter, ColumnCount).value = Application.index(MyArraY, 0, 0)
```

sometimes

`if MyArraY filling this way`

```
                    counter = 10
                    ReDim MyArraY(1 To counter)
                    For yy = 1 To counter
                    z = z + 1
                        If Cells(yy, 6).value = vbNullString Then
                            MyArraY(z) = Cells(yy, 5).value
                        Else
                            MyArraY(z) = Cells(yy, 6).value
                        End If

                    Next yy
```

`then`

```
 Cells(1, "B").Resize(counter, ColumnCount).value = Application.Transpose(MyArraY)
```

somtimes

`if`

```
MyArraY= range(Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(10, 5).Address).value

Cells(1, "B").Resize(counter, ColumnCount).value = MyArraY
```

How do I know when MyArray use one of this type? Because i always must a picking suitable type as i dont know how data is located in array

Comment: can you elaborate on this? I don't understand what you are demonstrating and what your question is.

Comment: Show me how look MyArraY in every cases

Comment: what do you mean !? How do you dimension your `myArray` variable? What's the value of `counter` and `ColumnCount` ?

Comment: There is no way of knowing whether you should or shouldn't transpose a 2D array other than by knowing how it was populated. For the former you have an array of arrays which is why you have to use Index to convert it to a 2D array. I don't see the point of the question - you must know how you populated your array.

Comment: Where is possible visual study how arrays works?

Comment: add to watch window and debug and see if you get what youre looking for... from your examples it will always be a Variant() but waht you are asking i dont know:O

Comment: How you understand what you must use Application.index instead of Application.Transpose or just MyArray? How you know how data is located in array? Or like me, using method of spear?

Answer (score -1):

You need to have the dimension of the array at hand. I do NOT think you did a ReDim Preserve to get the exact dimension of the array. That would help you correctly resize.
Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx

Comment: The question not about resize arrays